# How to test a function which uses a few well-tested but complicated functions?

Tags: unit-testing, integration-testing

I am an amateur in testing and is trying to learn how to write better tests. Right now I have the following pseudo code situation:

```
function doSomething() {
    context = prepare();
    result = doActualWork(context);
    notify(result);
}
```

You can imagine the `prepare()`, `doActgualWork()` and `notify()` are some complicated functions with many smaller functions inside, but they are covered by tests which may involve unit tests as well as integration and some involves HTTP/IO mockings.

Now when it comes to this `doSomething()` function, I am a bit confused on what I should do exactly to test it. One thing I think worth to test is the interfaces match: that is `context` returned by `prepare()` can be feed into `doActualWork()`, but then it is testing the actual implementation.

Another way could also be testing given an input it gives the correct output, since the underlying functions are quite complicated, I will need to mock all the HTTP/IO, this sounds a bit weird because I usually end up with big test cases with many preparation works, and the function call and assertion are just the last few lines.

It just doesn't feel right to do it this way.

Any help and guidance are appreciated. Thank you.

Answer (score 1):

You are already looking at this testing problem in the right way.

This piece of code is not suited for unit-testing: With unit-testing you try to find the bugs in small, isolated software pieces.  But, which bugs could be in this example code that are not related to the other components?  The bugs here are about questions like "am I calling the right functions with proper values for the arguments in the right argument order, is the other component in the right state (e.g. initialized), and are the return values and side effects as I expect them to be?"  All these questions are integration testing related.

Plus, there is another aspect of integration testing that is not focusing on the interactions but on the component as a whole - sometimes called component testing, subsystem testing etc.  This is about finding bugs like: "are the right versions of the components integrated, are all features that are expected from the component in place" etc.

Both these types of testing would make sense for this example piece of code, and both would be performed with the depended-on-components actually being in place in the right versions.  Whether you still use some mocks for indirect dependencies (like, mocks for the http requests happening inside the depended-on-components) is a different story.

In contrast, creating doubles/mocks for the calls to `prepare()`, `doActualWork()` and `notify()` just to be able to create unit-tests for `doSomething()` is not likely to help you in any way.  Since you implement these mocks, they will only reflect your potential misunderstanding of these functions.